# Flutter : A value of type 'List<Application>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Application>'

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-android

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:device_apps/device_apps.dart';

import 'package:app_uninstaller/app_uninstaller.dart';

import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';

import 'package:share/share.dart';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'dart:io';

import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class AppsListScreen extends StatelessWidget {

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return MaterialApp(


  theme: ThemeData(


    primarySwatch: Colors.red,),


  home: Scaffold(


    appBar: AppBar(


      title: Text("Banned Apps In Your Mobile"),


    ),


    body: appslist(),


    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,


  ),


  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,


  //backgroundColor: Colors.grey,


);
```

}

}

class appslist extends StatefulWidget {

@override

_appslist createState() => _appslist();

}

final AudioPlayer audioPlayer=AudioPlayer();

class _appslist extends State with WidgetsBindingObserver {

String uninstallStatus = "";

bool isEmpty = false;

DateTime now=new DateTime.now();

final ScreenshotController _screenshotcontroller = ScreenshotController();

List list=[];

AudioCache audioCache=AudioCache(fixedPlayer: audioPlayer);

bool stopAudio=false;

@override

void initState() {

```
// TODO: implement initState


WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);


super.initState();
```

}

@override

void dispose() {

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);


stop();


super.dispose();
```

}

@override

void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {

```
switch (state) {


  case AppLifecycleState.resumed:


    setState(() {});


    break;


}
```

}

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
double height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;


double width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;


return FutureBuilder <List<Application>>(


  future: DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(


    includeAppIcons: true,


  ),


  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot <List<Application>> data) {


    if (data.data == null) {


      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());


    } else {


      List<Application> apps = data.data;


      List<String> packageName = [


        'in.mohalla.sharechat',


        'com.tencent.mm',


        'com.tencent.mobileqq',


        'com.mncgames.play.kikorun',


        'com.getvoo.voodriver',


        'com.nimbuzz',


        'app.buzz.share',


        'com.qzone',


        'com.viber.voip',


        'jp.naver.line.android',


        'com.imo.android.imoim',


        'com.campmobile.snow',


        'com.ss.android.ugc.trill',


        'com.bsb.hike',


        'com.zhiliaoapp.musically',


        'video.like',


        'com.getsamosa',


        'com.lenovo.anyshare.gps',


        'cn.xender',


        'com.dewmobile.kuaiya.play',


        'com.UCMobile.intl',


        'com.uc.browser.en',


        'com.cmcm.live',


        'sg.bigo.live',


        'us.zoom.videomeetings',


        'com.uc.vmate',


        'com.asiainno.uplive',


        'com.cheerfulinc.flipagram',


        'com.intsig.camscanner',


        'com.commsource.beautyplus',


        'com.truecaller',


        'com.pubg.krmobile',


        'com.nono.android',


        'com.hcg.cok.gp',


        'com.mobile.legends',


        'club.fromfactory',


        'com.alibaba.aliexpresshd',


        'com.globalegrow.app.gearbest',


        'com.banggood.client',


        'com.miniinthebox.android',


        'com.tinydeal.android',


        'com.dhgate.buyer',


        'com.lightinthebox.android',


        'com.ericdress.application',


        'com.zaful',


        'com.tlz.tbdress',


        'com.rosegal',


        'com.zzkko',


        'com.romwe',


        'com.tinder',


        'com.trulymadly.android.app',


        'com.ftw_and_co.happn',


        'com.aisle.app',


        'com.coffeemeetsbagel',


        'com.okcupid.okcupid',


        'co.hinge.app',


        'com.azarlive.android',


        'com.bumble.app',


        'com.p1.mobile.putong',


        'de.affinitas.za.co.elitesingles.and',


        'com.taggedapp',


        'com.couchsurfing.mobile.android',


        'com.qihoo.security',


        'com.instagram.android',


        'co.ello.ElloApp',


        'com.snapchat.android',


        'com.eterno',


        'com.newsdog',


        'com.pratilipi.mobile.android',


        'com.luxeva.popxo',


        'com.capcipcup.mommp3',


        'com.yelp.android',


        'com.tumblr',


        'com.reddit.frontpage'


      ];


      List<String>appName = [


        'Kwali',


        'Fast Films',


        'All Tencent gaming Apps',


        'Chinabrands',


        'DX',


        'Modlity',


        'Woo',


        'Badoo',


        'Facebook',


        'Baidu',


        'Heal of Y',


        'Vokal',


        'Hungama',


        'FriendsFeed',


        'Private Blogs'


      ];


      apps.removeWhere((element) {


        return !packageName.contains(element.packageName) &&


            !appName.contains(element.appName);


      });





      if(apps.isEmpty){


        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){


          playMusic("a");


        });


      }


      if(apps.isNotEmpty){


        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){


          playMusic("b");


        });


      }





      return apps.isNotEmpty ? Scrollbar(


          child: ListView.builder(


              itemCount: apps.length,


              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {


                Application app = apps[position];


                if (apps.length == 0) {


                  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0), () {


                    setState(() {


                      isEmpty = true;


                    });


                  });


                } else if (apps.length > 0) {


                  return Column(


                    children: <Widget>[


                      ListTile(


                        leading: app is ApplicationWithIcon


                            ? CircleAvatar(


                          backgroundImage: MemoryImage(app.icon),


                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,


                        )


                            : null,


                        onTap: () async {


                          try {


                            bool isUninstalled =


                            await AppUninstaller.Uninstall(


                                app.packageName);


                            setState(() {


                              uninstallStatus = isUninstalled


                                  ? "Successfully Uninstalled!"


                                  : "Cancelled by user";


                            });


                          } on Exception {


                            uninstallStatus = "Some error occurred";


                          }


                        },


                        title:


                        Text('${app.appName} (${app.packageName})'),


                        subtitle: Text('Version: ${app.versionName}\n'


                            'System app: ${app.systemApp}\n'


                            'APK file path: ${app.apkFilePath}\n'


                            'Data dir: ${app.dataDir}\n'


                            'Installed: ${DateTime


                            .fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(


                            app.installTimeMillis).toString()}\n'


                            'Updated: ${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(


                            app.updateTimeMillis).toString()}'),


                        trailing: GestureDetector(


                          child: Icon(


                            Icons.delete,


                            size:


                            0.0,


                            color: Colors.redAccent,


                          ),


                          onTap: () async {


                            try {


                              bool isUninstalled =


                              await AppUninstaller.Uninstall(


                                  app.packageName);


                              setState(() {


                                uninstallStatus = isUninstalled


                                    ? "Successfully Uninstalled!"


                                    : "Cancelled by user";


                              });


                            } on Exception {


                              uninstallStatus = "Some error occurred";


                            }





                          },


                        ),


                      ),


                      const Divider(


                        height: 1.0,


                      )


                    ],


                  );


                }


                print("else is running");


                Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0), () {


                  setState(() {


                    isEmpty = true;


                  });


                });


                return Container();


              }


          )


      ) : Screenshot(


        controller: _screenshotcontroller,


        child: Container(


          color: Colors.white,


          height: height,


          width: width,


          child: Center(child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),


            child: Column(


              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,


              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,


              children: [





                Column(


                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,


                  children: [


                    Text("Scan Date:${now.day}/${now.month}/${now.year}",style: TextStyle(


                      fontSize: 20.0,


                    ),


                    ),


                    SizedBox(height: height*0.03,),


                    Text("Scan Time:${now.hour}:${now.minute}:${now.second}",style: TextStyle(


                      fontSize: 20.0,


                    ),


                    ),


                    SizedBox(height: height*0.07,),


                    Text("Your Phone is Secure", style: TextStyle(


                      color: Colors.red,


                      fontSize: 30.0,


                    ),


                    ),


                  ],


                ),


                SizedBox(height: height*0.07,),


                MaterialButton(


                  onPressed:() async {


                    Uint8List uint8List;


                    await _screenshotcontroller.capture(delay: Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((Uint8List image){


                      setState(() {


                        print("image empty=${image.isEmpty}");


                        uint8List=image;


                      });


                    });


                    String tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;


                    File file = File('$tempPath/image.png');


                    list.add(file.path);


                    await file.writeAsBytes(uint8List);


                    await Share.shareFiles(list);


                  },


                  minWidth: 280.0,


                  splashColor: Colors.green[800],


                  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,


                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(


                    vertical: 10.0,


                  ),


                  child: Text(


                    "SHARE",


                    style: TextStyle(


                      fontSize: 22.0,


                      color: Colors.white,


                    ),


                  ),


                ),


              ],


            ),


          ),


          ),


        ),


      );


    }


  },


);
```

}

void playMusic(String a) async{

```
if(a=="a"){


  await audioCache.loop("music/ok.wav");


}else{


  await audioCache.loop("music/danger.mp3");


}
```

}

void stop()async{

```
await audioPlayer.stop();
```

}

}`

I am trying create banned app uninstaller app

Comment: read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `List<Application> apps = data.data;` with `List<Application>? apps = data.data;`